# Missing loader for vuetify even though css-loader and vuetify-loader in package.json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I use vuetify for my web app. I have the necessary `vuetify.js` and the imports in the files.

When trying to build my app, I get the error:

> 'Module parse failed: unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.'

For tons of vuetify related files in the node_modules folder. For example:

`./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSelect/VSelect.js`

In my `package.json` I have:

1. `sass-loader`
2. `css-loader`
3. `vue-loader`
4. `vue-style-loader`
5. `vuetify-loader`

And a couple more defined (of which I think they have nothing to do with vuetify).

Could I be missing one? Do I need to define which one to use for the vuetify files?

Might be important to add: I don't have a `webpack.config.js`, therefore I cannot use the explanation on vuetify quickstart. Do I need a `webpack.config` to be able to solve this problem?

Comment: Webpack config for vue is in the Vue.config.js file: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html

Comment: If you are using Vue CLI, you must have `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify` installed then everything should works fine. If not you have to manually add webpack.config.js as it describe in https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#webpack-install.